# Approximate multidimensional sequences

Tags: time-series, approximation

I'm trying to find some method for approximating sequences.
I found Keogh's SAX symbolic approximation but it works for real valued time series and I have a database of about 3000 sequences, each one with a different number of elements, each element being of the form (a,r,b,c) where a, b and c are categorial variables and r is a real variable.

It is an heterogeneous multidimensional time series and I'm trying first of all to find state of the art techniques for treating them.

Please any hint on how to approach this?
Alessandra

Comment: I think that you may need to add more information in order to get a good answer to your question. For instance, are your sequences time series?

Comment: Yes they are if I use Keogh's definition: A time series is a collection of observations made sequentially in time. But each of my observations is a 4-tuple